# How to delete bytes from a byte array in between in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, byte

Given a byte array `buff` of length `n`:

```
unsigned char buff[n] = "....." // len n
```

I want to delete `m` characters at position `pos`,

`0 < pos, m, pos + m < n`

I tried using `memmove`:

`memmove(buff + pos, buff + pos + m, n - (pos + m) + 1);`

But this doesn't work for byte array as we don't have '\0' terminator for this buff (but we know its length)

How do I delete bytes in between? Anyone please help

Edit: Sample input,

Pos    Data
0000  03 00 02 ef 02 f0 80 64 00 08 03 **eb 70 82 e0 40**
0010  **00 ff 30 00 00 00 00 b3 47 43 00 00 00 00 00 00**
0020  **00 1e 00 c4** 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 00 65 00 66
0030  00 61 00 75 00 6c 00 74 00 41 00 6c 00 74 00 53

Say I want to delete the highlighted bytes from packet.

New paket,

Pos    Data
0000  03 00 02 ef 02 f0 80 64 00 08 03 00 00 00 00 00

0010  00 00 44 00 65 00 66 00 61 00 75 00 6c 00 74 00

0020  41 00 6c 00 74 00 53

Comment: If your only problem with `memmove` is the null terminator, add it after calling `memmove`.

Comment: Also note that the size of the array can't change, only the number of meaningful elements.

Comment: @ScottHunter This is not a char array it should not have a null terminator so I can't add it, its a data packet from network

Comment: Since you cannot resize `buff`, you'll have to make up your mind what to do with the unused bytes left over at the end. Personally, I wouldn't be to worried about them; if you don't use them, then you might as well leave them. Just make sure to register the new 'size' (i.e. the number of bytes that _are_ in use) somewhere for the rest of the application to know where the relevant data ends.

Comment: By the way, `n - (pos + m) + 1` is wrong; you are reading one byte too many, located outside of `buff`, which is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Then how can you have a problem w/ a missing null terminator?

Comment: What does this have to do with null terminators? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve] along with the expected content of `buff` after the call to `memmove`.

Comment: Be aware that you need to maintain the actual number of useful bytes. E.g: content of `buf` before deletion: `A,B,C,D`, number of useful bytes: `4`. Now you delete elements B and C: new content of `buff`: `A,D`, number of useful bytes: `2`

Comment: @RuudHelderman the +1 is for the null character in case of string

Comment: @RishabVArun thank you for editing, now could you also show how what content exactly you expect to be in `buff` _after_ the deletion?

Comment: @RishabVArun In `unsigned char buff[n]`, _n_ is not the length of the string (if any); it's the size of the buffer. A possible `'\0'` must be within the range of that buffer. Your `memmove` call is seeking for `'\0'` __outside__ of the buffer. Again, this is UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would erase `m` chars in an array without terminating null character.

```
int main() 
{
    int pos = 1, m = 3;
    
    unsigned char arr[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    memmove(arr + pos, arr + pos + m, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - pos - m);

  // if required to zero-out the remaining elements
   memset(arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - m, 0, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
        printf("%hhu ", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `1 5 6 7 8 0 0 0`

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for

Comment: That's the problem when you are in a hurry and not thinking things through, thanks, I will check

Comment: @Ruud corrected, thanks you are the man! I have to be more careful about this.. not much use in posting wrong answers :)

Comment: memcpy should be used here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Display(const char buff[], int nb)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    printf("%d ", buff[i]);

  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  unsigned char buff[20] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5 };
                      // buff has room for 20 elements
  int nbelements = 6; // but there are only 6 meaningful elements

  Display(buff, nbelements);

  int pos = 1;         // delete from element 1
  int nbtodelete = 2;  // delete 2 elements
  memmove(buff + pos, buff + pos + nbtodelete, nbelements - pos - 1);
  nbelements -= nbtodelete;

  Display(buff, nbelements);
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 3 4 5
```

It's pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Third memmove parameter is wrong, `nbelements - pos - 1` may cause memmove to read beyond buffer size. Should be `nbelements - pos - nbtodelete`.